# How can I get a paginated list of custom taxonomy tags with posts?

Tags: custom-taxonomy, pagination

I have a cpt (item), in which each post is assigned a single custom taxonomy tag (item_tags).

I want to list all tags, with description and linked titles of posts so-tagged.

I've had previous help here, and have found other code to list the tags and posts, but I can't paginate it - because they each use 'get_terms'.

The two existing options are (and, as pasted, have extra html formatting for my requirements):

```
$terms = get_terms('item_tags');
foreach ($terms as $term):
    ?>

    <?php echo apply_filters('the_content', $term->description) . '</dt>'; ?>
    <?php
    $posts = get_posts(array(
        'post_type' => 'item',
        'taxonomy' => $term->taxonomy,
        'term' => $term->slug,
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
        'order' => 'ASC',
    ));
    foreach ($posts as $post): // begin cycle through posts of this taxonmy
        setup_postdata($post); //set up post data for use in the loop (enables the_title(), etc without specifying a post ID)
        ?>
        <dd><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></dd>
    <?php endforeach;
    echo '</dl>' . "\n" . '<hr />' . "\n\n"; ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

And:

```
global $post;
$terms = get_terms(array(
    'taxonomy' => 'item_tags',
    'hide_empty' => false,
));
if (!empty($terms) && !is_wp_error($terms)) {
    foreach ($terms as $term) {
        echo apply_filters('the_content', $term->description);
        echo '</dt>' . "\n";
        $items = get_posts(array(
            'post_type' => 'item',
            'tax_query' => array(
                array(
                    'taxonomy' => 'item_tags',
                    'terms' => $term->term_id,
                ),
            ),
            'posts_per_page' => -1,
            'order' => 'ASC',
        ));
        foreach ($items as $post) {
            setup_postdata($post);
            ?>
            <dd><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></dd>
            <?php
        }
        echo '</dl>' . "\n" . '<hr />' . "\n\n";
    }
    wp_reset_postdata();
}
```

FURTHER UPDATE:

Although I still want to get the solution from Max Yudin working, I've an interim alternative using code Max and also from  https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/22101/125227 (suggested by  DHL17).

I'll include it here, as it may be useful to someone.

```
// Terms are formatted as ul.
// Posts are nested ul.  
// Has "\n" for line-break in source-code.

$args = array( 'hide_empty' => 1 );

$page = ( get_query_var('paged') ) ? get_query_var( 'paged' ) : 1;

// Number of tags to show per-page.
$per_page = 13;
$offset = ( $page-1 ) * $per_page;
$args = array( 'number' => $per_page, 'offset' => $offset,     'hide_empty' => 1 );


$taxonomy = 'item_tags';
$tax_terms = get_terms( $taxonomy, $args );

// Open ul for terms.
echo '<ul>' . "\n\n";

// Cycle through taxonomy terms, and open sub-ul for posts.
foreach ($tax_terms as $tax_term) {
echo '<li>' . '<a href="' . esc_attr(get_term_link($tax_term, $taxonomy)) . '" title="' . sprintf( __( "View all posts in %s" ), $tax_term->name ) . '" ' . '>' . $tax_term->name.'</a></li>' . "\n" . '<ul>' . "\n";

$post_type = 'item';
$taxonomy = 'item_tags';

// Cycle through posts for this term.
$items = get_posts( array (
'post_type'   => $post_type,
'tax_query'   => array(
array(
'taxonomy' => $taxonomy,
'terms'    => $tax_term->term_id,
), ),

// Set variables for posts-per-term
'numberposts' => -1,
'orderby' => 'date',
'order' => 'asc',
) );

global $post;

foreach ( $items as $item ) {

// Assign $item to global $post.
$post = $item;

// Post info to display.
setup_postdata( $post );
echo '<li><a href="' . get_the_permalink() . '">' . get_the_title() . '</a></li>' . "\n";
}

// Close sub-ul for posts.
echo '</ul>' . "\n\n";

// Reset.
wp_reset_postdata();
}

// Close ul for terms.
echo '</ul>' . "\n\n";


// Pagination.
$total_terms = wp_count_terms( 'item_tags' );
$pages = ceil($total_terms/$per_page);

if( $pages > 1 ):
echo '<ul>' . "\n";

for ($pagecount=1; $pagecount <= $pages; $pagecount++):
echo '<li><a href="'.get_permalink() . 'page/' . $pagecount . '/">' .     $pagecount . '</a></li>' . "\n";
endfor;
echo '</ul>';
endif;
```

Comment: Refer to this answer https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/22101/125227

Comment: @DHL17 Thanks. I'd looked at that before posting, but my brain went into fade-mode and I clearly didn't fully get it... I think because I was confused with the pagination I use for my WP-Query. I'll still need to find a way to insert the posts (which wasn't mentioned in my original title, now edited).

Answer (score 1):

<s>This code was not tested!</s>

#### Tested

Based on @Pieter Goosen [answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/228071/11761)
.

```
<?php
$post_type = 'item';
$taxonomy = 'item_tags';

// count the number of terms for correct pagination
$term_count = get_terms( array (
    'taxonomy' => $taxonomy,
    'fields'   => 'count',
) );

// define the number of terms per page
$terms_per_page = 10;

// find out the number of pages to use in pagination
$max_num_pages = ceil( $term_count / $terms_per_page );

// get the page number from URL query
$current_page = get_query_var( 'paged', 1 );

// calculate the offset, if there is one.
$offset = 0; // initial
// or changed the if not the first (0)
if( ! 0 == $current_page) {
    $offset = ( $terms_per_page * $current_page ) - $terms_per_page;
}

// get all taxonomy terms
$terms = get_terms( array (
    'taxonomy' => $taxonomy,
    'order'    => 'ASC',
    'orderby'  => 'name',
    'number'   => $terms_per_page,
    'offset'   => $offset,
) );

echo '<dl>';

// cycle through taxonomy terms
foreach ( $terms as $term ) {

    echo '<dt>' . $term->description . '</dt>';
    echo '<dd>'; 
    echo '<ul>'; // because you can't have multiple <dd>s for one <dt>

    // cycle through posts having this term
    $items = get_posts( array (
        'post_type'   => $post_type,
        'tax_query'   => array(
            array(
                'taxonomy' => $taxonomy,
                'terms'    => $term->term_id,
            ),
        ),
        'numberposts' => -1, // different from WP_Query (see Code Ref)
    ) );

    // essential, see comments inside foreach() loop
    global $post;

    foreach ( $items as $item ) {

        // assign $item to global $post 
        $post = $item;
        // and now set up 
        setup_postdata( $post );

        echo '<li><a href="' . get_the_permalink() . '">' . get_the_title() . '</a></li>';
        // wp_reset_postdata(); // see below
    }
    wp_reset_postdata(); // moved outside the foreach() loop

    // end posts cycle
    echo '</ul>';
    echo '</dd>';
}
// end term cycle
echo '</dl>';

// Pagination
// See the Code Reference for more arguments
echo paginate_links( array (
    'total'   => $max_num_pages,
    'current' => $current_page,
) );
```

Comment: Thanks. I need to find why, for the title-and-link of the posts, it's instead outputting the title+link of the test page it's currently on.

Comment: Oh, sorry. I didn't check your original code. See the fixed answer.

Comment: Thanks. It's almost there - but there's one issue... whatever is set in '$terms_per_page' is causing it to skip the first x terms. so if '$terms_per_page = 8', the first 8 tags are skipped.

Comment: OK. Let me test the code on my fresh dummy installation, but I could do it after 4-5 hours or tomorrow morning UTC+2. You also can make an effort if you are pressed for time.

Comment: Thanks. There's no rush, whatever/whenever you can do is hugely appreciated... I'll continue to look at it - more as something from which I can learn (I'm a novice at this), than in hope of a fix.

Comment: There was wrong `$offset` calculation for the first (0) page in pagination. It's fixed and tested now. Pretty easy, huh?

Comment: When you try to do something yourself, there are some tests. Print out `$current_page` and print out `$offset`. When you see some correlation between them, then you are on the finish line. But you've never tried. Never ask me for help anуmore.

Comment: Thanks for your help, and suggestions about $current_page and $offset. I'm learning, but it's slow and difficult. I'll return to the code when I know more... I'm getting two issues, both affected by the '$terms_per_page' setting. With '$terms_per_page = -1', only 1 term is shown - and with no pagination. And, currently querying 48 terms, when '$terms_per_page = 23' (or lower), links to only the first and last pages are shown. But I don't know enough to even begin a fix. In addition to my own requirement, I always hope my questions at SEWPD lead to code which helps others. :-)

Comment: The site is about _development_ not 'write the code instead of me'. I gave you the idea, the rest is up to you. Don't use `-1` which means "show all". You need just some tags per page. Navigation is the subject to be set up, [just read](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/paginate_links) the documentation.

Comment: I'm appreciative of what you've done, and have no wish to get into potential unpleasantness. Although neither I nor anyone else has asked you to write any code, of course the hope of myself and many others who post here is that someone will be kind enough to provide such a solution by doing exactly that - supply code. That's often how many of us learn - by looking at a solution, which then helps us to understand something better than we otherwise could have, rather than continuing to try-and-fail to get there unaided. Prior to any post I search/try extensively. :-)

Comment: A brief addition... much of the way 'the world learns' nowadays is through someone having asked a question, to which an answer is supplied by someone appropriately knowledgeable, and which is then also used by someone else. In this way 'we all grow' - the ignorant through becoming wiser, and the knowledgeable through sharing their abilities. And rather than simply 'development', WPSE is also 'for administrators and management best practices' - a wide area which should reasonably be able to include many of the questions here (including those which sometimes unreasonably get closed).

Comment: @glvr, sorry, I was drunk again and accordingly behaved badly. I meant we have to share our time making efforts to achieve your goal. Otherwise it's a one-sided relationships.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. Honestly, I wish I understood enough to not need to ask so much. But, it quickly gets beyond my ability. Although it's not relevant, I try to help others elsewhere where able, sharing my knowledge/ability in other things (business advice/etcetera) - a situation in which I've often thought 'jeez, couldn't they have tried harder to work this out themselves?'. But, overall, I've decided that if I've volunteered to help, I'll do so without (too much) judgment. It's one-sided, similar to how I receive-not-give here. My genuine best wishes and thanks to you. :-)

Comment: If you cannot see the next link, make the current page equals to: `$current_page = ( get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) ? get_query_var( 'paged' ) : 1;`